# How to send multiple models to one form for a has_many / belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, a `Vehicle` model can have multiple `Driver` models, and a `Base` model can also have multiple `Driver` models. Right now the associations are setup like so:

`vehicle.rb`:

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
has_many :drivers
```

`base.rb`:

```
class Base < ApplicationRecord
has_many :drivers
```

`driver.rb`:

```
class Driver < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :vehicle
belongs_to :base
```

When a user is using the app, they cannot access drivers unless they have already added a vehicle, i.e., a vehicle has a unique set of drivers that are accessible to that vehicle and only that vehicle, as a driver cannot drive more than one vehicle at a time.

Where I'm stumbling is implementing the `Base` model association. A base can affiliate with multiple drivers at any given time, but a driver can only affiliate with one base at at time.

What I would prefer for my app to be able to do:
When adding a new `Driver`, I would like the user to be able to add the driver's base information as well. Due to the nature of how bases work, a base can already exist in the bases table before a driver is added. If the base exists, the driver is simply added to the drivers table with a reference to the pre-existing base in the bases table. If the base does not already exist, i.e., this is the first time this specific base has been affiliated with by any driver, add the base to the bases table, and add the driver to the drivers table with the reference to the correct base in the bases table.

In `drivers_controller.rb`, I'm passing in a new `Base` instance:

```
def new
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(vehicle_id)
    @base = Base.new
    @driver = Driver.new
end

def create
    render plain: params[:base].inspect
    # other misc code
end
```

Upon inspection of the `:base` parameter, I see that `nil` is returned, which makes sense since I'm not doing anything with the `@base` instance variable in the `new.html.erb` view for the `DriverController`. I already have a partial form for the `BaseController` and the `DriverController`. Is there a way for me to render both partial forms, and submit one form for multiple models? Is this a bad idea? How can I go about achieving my end result?

For reference, my `new.html.erb` for the `DriverController`:

```
# add a @base reference in the following line?
<%= form_with model: @driver, url: vehicle_drivers_path(@vehicle), local: true do |form| %>
    # render the base partial here?
    <%= render 'form', form: form %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested attributes in this case. [Refer active record nested attributes here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)